# pivot groupby and sum pandas dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, group-by, pivot

This should be simple, but i'm new to working in python. Any suggestions please?

```
#original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1,1,1,1,1],
                   'month':[4,4,4,4,4],
                   'mode': ['a','b','a','a','b']},
                  columns=['year','month','mode'])

#pivot/groupby etc
# df2=df.pivot(columns=('year','month'), values=('mode')).count()

#create this dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year':[1],
                   'month':[4],
                   'a': [3],
                   'b':[2]},
                  columns=['year','month','a','b'])
```

I'm working in Koalas Apache Spark environment ([documentation](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)), so solution should work on it.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index=['year','month'], aggfunc='size', columns='mode')`

Comment: thanks, if you post as an answer i'll accept it in case it helps someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['year','month'], aggfunc='size', columns='mode')
```

Comment: If i use the method on a koalas dataframe (apache spark) I get an error - "values should be string or list of one column". What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively You can use `pd.get_dummies()`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df).groupby(['year','month']).sum()
```

result:

```
            mode_a  mode_b
year month                
1    4           3       2
```

Note: I'm not sure that works in Koalas Apache Spark environment.

Comment: thanks, but get_dummies is not a koalas function and therefore the method won't work